# Dynamically create an array of inputs in React

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm still a novice at the React framework. I'm working on a project where I would like to allow the user to create select fields. I am currently using react-select to render the select fields or dropdowns. I need the values that they selected from the select input fields. The problem is the user needs to be able create multiple input fields. Each input field must have a unique key. I want to be able to retrieve the values as they as they choose them.

What follows is what I have so far:

```
 class OptionsComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    fields: [],
    parentArray: [],
    optionsArray: [],
    selectedOption:'',

   };

this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this); 
}

 handleSelect = (event, index) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(optionsArray);
  console.log(selectedOption);
  const optionsArray = [...this.state.optionsArray];
  let selectedOption = event.label;
  optionsArray[index]= event.target.value;

  this.setState({
    optionsArray,
    selectedOption: event.label,
  })}

 render(){

return(

  <div className="">
    <div className="optionsArea">

      { this.state.parentArray.map((el, index) =>
        <div key={index} className="selectDropdown ">
            { this.state.optionsArray.map((el, index) => {
              return <Select
              key={index}
              name="optionsSelect"
              className="userOptionSelectDropdown"
              placeholder="Select Variable"
              value={this.state.selectedOption}
              onChange={(event) => this.handleSelect(event)}
              onSelect={(event) => this.handleSelect(event)}
              options={this.state.fields.map((field, index) => {
              return {value: index, label: field.name;
            })} />
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }
    </div>

  </div>

    );
   }
 }
```

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate. I checked the similar questions and did a google search and I couldn't find anything. Right now when I use this code in my component, it doesn't render anything. I'm not really sure why. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the name of the component and get it during your handleSelect and get the value directly (works if you use custom controls from bootstrap 4 for example). Remember to use a different name for the index in the options.

```
handleSelect = (event) => {
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value; 

    // perform action

    ...

}
```

and then in your render generate a unique name in the map, something like `name={"optionsSelect_" + el + "_" + index}` or whatever you like:

```
...

{ this.state.parentArray.map((el, index) =>
    <div key={index} className="selectDropdown ">
        { this.state.optionsArray.map((el, index) => {
          return <Select
          key={index}
          name={"optionsSelect_" + el + "_" + index}
          className="userOptionSelectDropdown"
          placeholder="Select Variable"
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={(event) => this.handleSelect(event)}
          onSelect={(event) => this.handleSelect(event)}
          options={this.state.fields.map((field, index2) => {
          return {value: index2, label: field.name;
        })} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

...
```

If setting the name doesn't work, you can try references as well:

```
...

{ this.state.parentArray.map((el, index) =>
    <div key={index} className="selectDropdown ">
        { this.state.optionsArray.map((el, index) => {
          return <Select
          key={index}
          ref={a => (this["optionsSelect_" + el + "_" + index] = a)}
          name={"optionsSelect_" + el + "_" + index}
          className="userOptionSelectDropdown"
          placeholder="Select Variable"
          value={this.state.selectedOption}
          onChange={(event) => this.handleSelect(event)}
          onSelect={(event) => this.handleSelect(event)}
          options={this.state.fields.map((field, index2) => {
          return {value: index2, label: field.name;
        })} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
...
```

and then get it in your handle (you get the complete component):

```
handleSelect = (event) => {
    let name = event.target.name;
    let element = this[name]; 

    // perform action

    ...

}
```

There are a lot of ways of getting the selected value using pure javascript, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript).

**This is very important!**

if you need to modify the state based on a previous state, don't do this:

```
    ...
    const optionsArray = [...this.state.optionsArray];
    let selectedOption = event.label;
    optionsArray[index]= event.target.value;

    this.setState({
        optionsArray,
        selectedOption: event.label,
    })
    ...
```

The setState also receives a function, and will give you the previous state for you to handle it, make any changes you need, and **ENSURE** that they will be set correctly.

```
    ...    
    this.setState(prevState => {
        // get current state
        let newOptionsArray = prevState.optionsArray;
        let selectedOption = event.label; // or whatever
        newOptionsArray[index]= event.target.value; // or whatever

        return({
            optionsArray: newOptionsArray,
            selectedOption: event.label,
        });
    });
    ...
```

Have a read [in the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to understand how setState works.

Comment: Are refs considered to be bad practice? I thought I read that refs are supposed to be considered a last resort. Or are they okay to use in React?

Comment: If you can avoid them don't it's better to use alternative approaches, but if there is no alternative use them. I always use the handle approach for this case, and get the name and value using the handle, updating the state with these.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood exactly what you're asking/trying to do, but I believe this will do it:

1. Intializes a Select field with options
2. Creates a new Select field with options from user input
3. Each Field stores the selected option (if one was selected)
4. Clicking "Submit Form" shows all the selected options

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/81jlqp31p9

```
import each from "lodash/each";
import map from "lodash/map";
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default class DynamicSelect extends Component {
  state = {
    Fields: [
      {
        name: "Field0",
        options: [
          { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
          { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
          { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
        ]
      }
    ],
    selectedOptions: {}
  };

  clearSelections = () => this.setState({ selectedOptions: [] });

  handleChange = (name, value) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectedOptions: [
        ...this.state.selectedOptions,
        {
          name: value
        }
      ]
    }));
  };

  handleAddField = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const { newFields } = this.state;
      if (!newFields) return;
      const arr = newFields.split(",");
      const options = map(arr, val => ({ value: val, label: val }));

      return {
        newFields: "",
        Fields: [
          ...this.state.Fields,
          {
            name: `Field${this.state.Fields.length}`,
            options
          }
        ]
      };
    });
  };

  handleFieldChange = e => {
    this.setState({ newFields: e.target.value });
  };

  showSelectedOptions = selectedOptions => {
    return map(selectedOptions, ({ name }) => name + "");
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { selectedOptions } = this.state;

    alert(`Selection option(s): ${this.showSelectedOptions(selectedOptions)}`);
  };

  render() {
    const { Fields, newFields, selectedOptions } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{ margin: 20 }}>
        <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Dynamic Select Fields</h3>
        {!isEmpty(Fields) &&
          map(Fields, ({ name, options }, key) => (
            <div key={key} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
              <div>{name}:</div>
              <Select
                name={name}
                value={selectedOptions[name]}
                onChange={({ value }) => this.handleChange(name, value)}
                options={options}
                style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <input
            style={{ marginBottom: 5, width: "100%" }}
            type="text"
            className="uk-input"
            onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
            placeholder="Create a Select Field (option, option, option, ..etc)"
            value={newFields}
          />
          <br />
          <button
            onClick={this.handleAddField}
            className="uk-button uk-button-default"
            type="button"
            disabled={newFields ? false : true}
          >
            Add Field
          </button>
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
          <button
            className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
            type="submit"
            disabled={!isEmpty(selectedOptions) ? false : true}
          >
            Submit Form
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```